# Typescript namespace.type<Interface, Interface, {}> syntaxis

Tags: typescript

I'am new to typescript and trying to fix index.d.ts typescript declaration file for [fastify-static plugin](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static)

index.d.ts looks like this:

```
import fastify = require("fastify");

import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";
import { Http2SecureServer, Http2ServerRequest, Http2ServerResponse } from "http2"

declare module "fastify" {
    interface FastifyReply<HttpResponse> {
        sendFile(filename: string): FastifyReply<HttpResponse>;
    }
}

declare const fastifyStatic: fastify.Plugin<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse , {
    root: string;
    prefix?: string;
    serve?: boolean;
    decorateReply?: boolean;
    schemaHide?: boolean;
    setHeaders?: (...args: any[]) => void;
    redirect?: boolean;
    wildcard?: boolean | string;

    // Passed on to `send`
    acceptRanges?: boolean;
    cacheControl?: boolean;
    dotfiles?: boolean;
    etag?: boolean;
    extensions?: string[];
    immutable?: boolean;
    index?: string[];
    lastModified?: boolean;
    maxAge?: string | number;
}>;

export = fastifyStatic;
```

I need to change this declaration file so const fastifyStatic will accept interfaces

```
Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse
```

or

```
Http2SecureServer, Http2ServerRequest, Http2ServerResponse
```

Problem is that i can't really understand syntaxis of datatype:

```
fastify.Plugin<Interface, Interface, {}>
```

I would appreciate explanation of this or some documentation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the syntax for [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

In this case, it looks like you are providing typings for up to 4 things that `fastify.Plugin` would use internally or expose in its own type.